# New user role in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I created new user `role (Manager)` in WordPress in my functions.php file. This is my code, but it not functional. The Manager only read the posts, can't edit and delete. What's wrong?

Thx.

```
function ui_new_role() {  

    //add the new user role
    add_role(
        'manager',
        'Manager',
        array(

    'edit_'              => true,
    'read_'              => true,
    'delete_'            => true,


    'edit_s'             => true,
    'edit_others_s'      => true,
    'publish_s'          => true,
    'read_private_s'     => true,


    'delete_s'           => true,
    'delete_private_s'   => true,
    'delete_published_s' => true,
    'delete_others_s'    => true,
    'edit_private_s'     => true,
    'edit_published_s'   => true,
        )
    );

}
add_action('admin_init', 'ui_new_role');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new "Manager" role.

```
$result = add_role(
    'manager',
    __( 'Manager' ),
    array(
        'read'         => true,  // true allows this capability
        'edit_posts'   => true,
        'delete_posts' => true, // Use false to explicitly deny
    )
);
if ( null !== $result ) {
    echo 'New role created!';
}
else {
    echo 'Manager role already exists.';
}
```

[reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role)

Comment: Sorry, but still not function it. The user only read the posts.

Comment: Are you using cache plugin if then delete all caches.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) you're adding the role incorrectly. Your privilege names don't match anything I know of. In my opinion it's much better to add via a plugin.

```
function add_mgr_role()
{
    add_role(
        'manager',
        'Manager',
        array(
            'read' => true,
            'edit_posts' => true,
            'delete_posts' => true
        )
    );
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'add_mgr_role');
```